# Checking If NEW Outlook is running and sending emails if it is

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-automation

I have a desktop application that checks if Outlook is running and if it is sends an email.

My customer has just upgraded Outlook to "NEW" Outlook and this section of the application has now stopped working

The code I am using to check if Outlook is running is

```
   If isAppThere("Outlook.Application") = False Then

                MsgBox("Outlook is closed. Please start up Outlook")
                Exit Sub

Function isAppThere(appName) As Boolean

        Dim objApp As Object
        On Error GoTo OUTERR
        isAppThere = True
        objApp = GetObject(, appName)
OUTERR:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            isAppThere = False
        End If


    End Function
```

If I remove this section and get the program to try and send an email via Outlook I get an error "Retrieving the COM class for Component with CLSID ..... failed due to the following error 80080005 Server execution failed".

Another user running the same program with the old version of Outlook has no issues. Clearly the "NEW" Outlook is causing the issue. So how do I check if this version is running and how do I send emails via this new version?

Thanks in advance

Please see above. I have tried to send an email via NEW outlook

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send or do anything programmatically with the new Outlook - it has no publicly available API.

Your only option is to tell the customers not to downgrade to the new Outlook - it is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar, not desktop Outlook, which is still fully supported.

Comment: Dmitry, do you know if Microsoft’s ultimate goal is to replace classic Outlook with new Outlook? If so how many years do we have left on classic Outlook? I can’t find any references to what their direction is. Thanks

Comment: from what I hear we still have years - MS will announce the switch 12 month in advance. Then it will be another 12 months before Office subscription is no longer available.  IMHO, it will be at least 5 years from now.

Answer (score 1):

lInstead of getting the running Outlook application instance you can just check the list of running processes.

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName("Outlook").Length < 1 Then
   ' not running 
End If
```